# Kerberos Authentication Headers in CometD with Jetty

Tags: jetty, cometd

I am deploying my cometd in jetty container. I want to pass kerberos credentials with the request. What should be the correct way to pass kerberos credential headers with the request which can work with all kind of transports (websockets, longpolling and callbackpolling).

Thanks,

Anuj

Comment: please indicate if the client is a browser or some other form of client (like a standalone application, mobile app, command line, or something else that isn't a browser)

Comment: Yes the client is browser only.

Comment: See prior answer about javascript websocket authentication http://stackoverflow.com/a/22608447/775715